# What is the proper way to handle access denied on file download WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
 public FileResult DownloadDocument(VMUserProfile userprofile, int UploadDocumentID)
    {
        //This method will get a file from the database and 
        //Permissions will be checked 
    }
```

if the user does not have the proper access to download the file how would you handle letting the user know its access denied ? Throw a IO Exception ?

Comment: ok but there is not exception being thrown .... all this doing is checking permissions and it is determined that the user does not have any permissions to access the referenced file.

Comment: With such a small amount of information about requirements, the best things I would imagine will be suggested would be to use a try/catch block; when you capture the exception (making it easier to properly log and debug), handle the UnauthorizedAccessException or 403 status code on the UI and give the end user a more user-friendly message.

Comment: In this case the method signature indicates that the intended function is to download a document, not to check its permissions - your initial instinct to throw an exception for a known use case is probably reasonable then.

Comment: Cool I think I will throw a System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)

Comment: You probably want 'Forbidden' rather than 'NotFound' in this instance - the file _does_ exist, you just aren't allowed to access it.

Comment: Good call if you put a answer ill accept it

Comment: I suggest you check permissions first and then get file.  check out Asp.Net Identity then you can use Authorize attribute on Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the small amount of information provided, answers are going to be hard to make concise. That being said:

Your assumption of throwing an exception makes sense given the method signature; `DownloadDocument` *clearly* expects that it can actually perform a download. Since it will fail under and expected set of circumstances that occur under regular use:

- Throw some type of exception (in this case, since we are talking about ASP.NET, we will want to use an `HttpResponseException` so that an `HttpResponseMesssage` is returned to the client with the relevant 403 status code)
- On the client controller, you can then use an exception handler to generate the proper logging and stack traces for developers while also creating a user-friendly error message to display on the UI

If you have more specific needs, you are going to have to implement more advanced handling, but it seems like you have a good idea of the general premise with your initial intuition.